# How to save a QStandardItemModel?

Tags: model-view-controller, qt

I'm currently writing an application that plays podcasts. I'm representing all the feeds and the episodes within them as `QStandardItem` objects within a `QStandardItemModel`. Right now, I don't have a way to save this model--when the application closes, the feed model goes up in smoke. I looked at using `QSettings`, but that only works for datatypes that fall under `QVariant`.

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279649/convert-a-qstandarditemmodel-to-a-qvariant) gave me some hope, but I think I'm doing something wrong. I've got the following code in the constructor for my application.

```
//Expand QVatiant to use QStandardItemModel
qRegisterMetaType<QStandardItemModel>("QStandardItemModel");
```

That, however, gives me this error at compile time.

```
/ [...] QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/4/Headers/qstandarditemmodel.h:424: error: 'QStandardItemModel::QStandardItemModel(const QStandardItemModel&)' is private
```

Ah. That reminds me of this caveat from the Qt documentation for QMetaType, [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType).

> Any class or struct that has a public default constructor, a public copy constructor and a public destructor can be registered.

So, where do I go from here? Qt is behaving exactly as it should, so this approach won't work.  I'm thinking of saving off the model as an xml file, but that seems like a ton of effort. This seems like a pretty common problem--I just don't know where to look for the answer.

Comment: Looks like there's no good way to do this...I'll probably have to serialize this into a file somehow. I'll follow up with my own solution.

Comment: As far as I know, you need to derive a class from QStandardItemModel and implement a public copy-constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the best solution I could come up with: Create a method that saves the model into an XML document, and call it whenever I change the model (e.g. add or remove a podcast). I don't have the actual source code on hand, but since there's no real easy way to save the data structure wholesale, this is the best solution.